# Vertica's vsql.exe returns errorlevel 0 when facing ERROR 3326: Execution time exceeded run time cap

Tags: timeout, vertica, errorlevel, vsql

I am using vsql.exe on an external Vertica database for which I don't have any administrative access. I use some views with simple `SELECT+FROM+WHERE` queries.
These queries 90% of the time work just fine, but some times, randomly, I get this error:

```
ERROR 3326:  Execution time exceeded run time cap of 00:00:45
```

The strange thing is that this error can happen *way after those 45 seconds*, even after 3 minutes. I've been told this is related to having different resource pools, but anyway I don't want to dig into that.

The problem is that when this occurs, `vsql.exe` returns `errorlevel 0` and there is (apparently almost) no way to know this failed.

The output of the query is stored in a csv file. When it succeeds, it ends with `(#### rows)`. But when it fails with this error, it just stops at any point of the csv, and its resulting size is around half of what's expected. This is of course not what you would expect when an error occurs, like no output or an empty one.
If there is a connection error or if the query has syntax errors, the errorlevel is not 0, so in those cases it behaves as expected.

I've tried many things, like increasing the timeout or adding `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=ON` to the vsql.exe parameters, but none of that helped.

I've googled a lot and found many people having this error, but the solutions are mostly related to increasing the timeouts, not related to the errorlevel returned.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**TL;DR**: how can I detect an error 3326 in a batch file like this?

```
@echo off
vsql.exe -h <hostname> -U <user> -w <pwd> -o output.cs -Ac "SELECT ....;"
echo %errorlevel% is always 0
if errorlevel 1 echo Error!! But this is never displayed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that's really unexpected to me. I don't have Windows available just now, but trying on my Mac - at first just triggering a deliberate error:

```
$ vsql -h zbook -d sbx -U dbadmin -w $VSQL_PASSWORD  -v ON_ERROR_STOP=ON -Ac "select * from foobarfoo"
ERROR 4566:  Relation "foobarfoo" does not exist
$ echo $?
1
```

With `ON_ERROR_STOP` set to `ON`, this should be the behaviour everywhere.

Could you try what I did above through Windows, just with `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` instead of `echo $?`, just from the Windows command prompt and not in a batch file?

Next test: I run on resource pool `general` in my little test database, so I temporarily modify it to a runtime cap of 30 sec, run a silly query that *will* take over 30 seconds with `ON_ERROR_STOP` set to `ON`, collect the value returned by `vsql` and set the runtime cap of `general` back to `NONE`. I also have the `%VSQL_* %` env variables set so I don't have to repeat them all the time:

```bash
rem Windows way to set environment variables for vsql:
set VSQL_HOST=zbook
set VSQL_DATABASE=sbx
set VSQL_USER=dbadmin
set VSQL_PASSWORD=***masked***
```

Now for the test (backslashes, in Linux/MacOs escape a new line, which enables you to "word wrap" a shell command. Use the caret (`^`) in Windows for that):

```bash
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ # set a runtime cap
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ vsql -i -c \
"alter resource pool general runtimecap '00:00:30'"
ALTER RESOURCE POOL
Time: First fetch (0 rows): 116.326 ms. All rows formatted: 116.730 ms
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ vsql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=ON -iAc \
 "select count(*) from one_million_rows a cross join one_million_rows b" 
ERROR 3326:  Execution time exceeded run time cap of 00:00:30
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ # test the return code
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ echo $?
1
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ # clear the runtime cap
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ vsql -i -c \
"alter resource pool general runtimecap NONE  "   
ALTER RESOURCE POOL
Time: First fetch (0 rows): 11.148 ms. All rows formatted: 11.383 ms
```

So it works in my case. Your line:

`if errorlevel 1 echo Error!! But this is never displayed.`

... never echoes anything because the previous line, with `echo` will return 0 to the shell, overriding the previous `errorlevel`.

Try it command by command on your Windows command prompt, and see what happens. Just `echo %errorlevel%`, without evaluating it.

And I notice that you are trying to export to CSV format. Then, try this:

- Format the output unaligned (`-A`)
- set the field separator to comma (`-F ','`)
- remove the footer '(n rows)' (`-P footer`)
- limit the output to 5 rows in the query for test

(I show the output before redirecting to file):

```
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ vsql -A -F ',' -P footer -c "select * from one_million_rows limit 5"
id,id_desc,dob,category,busid,revenue
0,0,1950-01-01,1,====== boss ========,0.000
1,-1,1950-01-02,2,kbv-000001kbv-000001,0.010
2,-2,1950-01-03,3,kbv-000002kbv-000002,0.020
3,-3,1950-01-04,4,kbv-000003kbv-000003,0.030
4,-4,1950-01-05,5,kbv-000004kbv-000004,0.040
```

Not aligning is much faster than aligning.
Then, as you spend most time in the fetching of the rows (that's because you get a timeout in the middle of an output file write process), try fetching more rows at a time than the default 1000. You will need to play with the value, depending on the network settings at your site until you get your best value:

- `-v ROWS_AT_A_TIME=10000`

Once you're happy with the tested output, try this command (change the `SELECT` for your needs, of course ....):

```bash
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ vsql -A -F ',' -P footer \ 
-v ON_ERROR_STOP=ON -v ROWS_AT_A_TIME=10000 -o one_million_rows.csv  \
-c "select * from one_million_rows"         
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ wc -l one_million_rows.csv 
 1000001 one_million_rows.csv
```

The table actually contains one million rows. Note the line count in the file: 1,000,001. That's the title line included, but the footer `(1000000 rows)` removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the time you took to investigate. I'll try to respond to the main points:
`1.` As mentioned in my question, errors in the query, like syntax errors (or missing tables) behave as expected, errorlevel is 1.
`2.` I tried `alter resource pool general runtimecap` to see if that made a difference, but I don't have permission for it.
`3.` `echo` and `if` commands don't affect the errorlevel. You can call them many times and the value stays. I double checked just in case. :)
`4.` The output was already unaligned (`-Ac`). Aligning such a huge result would have been ugly.

Comment: `5.` The default separator is a pipe `|`, to change it to comma I had to use `-F ,` without apostrophes, but I don't think that made a difference.
`6.` The footer is useful as only successful queries have it in the output. Still removed it though.
`7.` Which version of vsql are you using? Mine is `09.03.0100`.
`8.` I tried `ROWS_AT_A_TIME=10000` and got 70K rows (should have been like 700K).
`ERROR 3326:  Execution time exceeded run time cap of 00:00:45. Time: First fetch (10000 rows): 10244.000 ms. All rows formatted: 47777.000 ms`

Comment: `9.` A second attempt worked, and the output was `Time: First fetch (10000 rows): 39200.000 ms. All rows formatted: 375126.000 ms`.
`10.` I'll try other `ROWS_AT_A_TIME` values, but I'm afraid that won't make a difference.
`11.` We actually use a console app to call vsql, I might try to change the exit code if the standard error output is not empty, to *work around* this issue with vsql.exe.
Sorry for the long comments.

Comment: You don't need to change `general`'s runtime cap, as you are running through a different resource pool than `general` already, and that one's runtime cap is at 45 seconds already. My `vsql --version` returns: `vsql version 11.00.0200, built for OSX, contains support for command-line editing`. I need the single quotes around the comma in MacOS and Linux, as the comma has an important meaning in the interaction with their shells (zsh and bash respectively)